# How do we use the result of one function in another (Haskell)?

Tags: haskell

I would like to test if a a series of 3 inputs can together form a triangle, before calculating the area.

to see if they can form a triangle i have:

```
test :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Bool
test a b c
    | a>0 && b>0 && c>0 && a+b>c && c+b>a &&c+a > b= True
    | otherwise = False
```

To calculate the area i have:

```
sqrt(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))
where s= (a+b+c)/2
```

I thought maybe something like this would work:

```
area_of_triangle :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Bool-> Maybe Float
area_of_triangle
    | test== True = sqrt(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))  
    | True = Nothing
        where s= (a+b+c)/2
```

but it returns the error:

```
Solution.hs:8:31: Not in scope: ‘a’

Solution.hs:8:36: Not in scope: ‘b’

Solution.hs:8:41: Not in scope: ‘c’

Solution.hs:10:19: Not in scope: ‘a’

Solution.hs:10:21: Not in scope: ‘b’

Solution.hs:10:23: Not in scope: ‘c’
```

Comment: So many things wrong. `sqrt(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))` is invalid syntax. The type of `area_of_triangle` is wrong. `area_of_triangle` doesn't have arguments, yet you try to name them. And you compare a function against a boolean. Break your code into smaller pieces and get them to work individually.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: it's strictly speaking not invalid syntax, it just requires an utter bogus type of `s`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Can `s(s-a)` really be typed?

Comment: @chi: `class BogusS a where s :: a` with `instance BogusS Int` and `instance BogusS (Int->Int)` would do it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Uh, right! `s :: a ; s=s` also works. Thanks.

Comment: @chi bottom always works ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no need to test a boolean in order to return `True` or `False`: just return the boolean!

```
test :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Bool
test a b c = a>0 && b>0 && c>0 && a+b>c && c+b>a && c+a>b
```

Then, for the other function:

We have to add arguments `a b c`, and multiplication signs `*`.

We need to use `Just` in the first case to turn a `Float` into a `Maybe Float`.

`test` needs its three arguments.

Also, there is no point in checking whether `boolean == True` -- just use the boolean!

Finally, why the `Bool` argument? We don't need that -- let's remove it.

```
area_of_triangle :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe Float
area_of_triangle a b c
    | test a b c = Just (sqrt (s * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c)))
    | otherwise  = Nothing
        where s = (a+b+c)/2
```

It is common in Haskell to use `camelCase` for function names. Consider renaming your function to `areaOfTriangle` to follow the convention.

Comment: One might also consider getting rid of `test` as a separate function or at least making it local to `areaOfTriangle`. I'd just inline the condition in this specific example.

Comment: Another to consider is making a Triangle type (`data Triangle = Tri {a :: Float, b :: Float, c :: Float}`) and then make a [smart constructor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors).